# When to use -ris vs. -re as a passive verbal ending

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, contraction

Anyone who has read Cicero's famous line,

> Quo usque tandem, Catalina, abutere patientia nostra?

...knows that the 2nd person singular passive personal ending "-ris" is often changed to "-re":

- laudaris > laudare
- hortaberis > hortabere
- mittaris > mittare
- audireris > audirere

Some of these--*especially* "mittare"--sound pretty strange to me. Others seem natural.

I have two related questions:

- Are there rules or guidelines, beyond obvious metrical constraints, about when to use either form?
- Do we have information about the relative frequency of -ris vs. -re?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have precise figures for frequency, but G&L §1301b say that it is very common in earlier prose, less common in later:

> In the second Singular, passive, in all tenses of the Present stem, the ending **-re** is much more common in early Latin than **-ris,** and is regular in Cic. except in the Pr. Indic., where he prefers **-ris** on account of confusion with Pr. Inf., admitting **-re** only in deponents, and then but rarely.  In general, in the Pr. Indic. **-re** is rare in the first and second conjugations, more rare in the third, and never found in the fourth, in prose authors.  Post-Ciceronian prose writers, *e.g.*, Livy, Tacitus, prefer **-ris,** even in the other tenses of the Present stem.  The poets use **-ris** or **-re** to suit metre.

For those unfamiliar with G&L's terminology, by "Present tenses" they mean all tenses formed from the present stem: for *amare*, that's *am(a)-* and not *amav-*.

For general advice on Latin composition, *amabare* is fine, but *amare* could cause confusion, so *amaris* is preferred. Note that even [*amere*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=amere) has been used in poetry, and although [*mittare*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=mittare) has not, *admittare* and *transmittare* have.